# Persist List Id and list item ID During Migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, id, sharepointmigrationtool, metalogix

I am planning to use metalogix to migrate the SharePoint list. Is it possible to persist the List-Id and list item id?

If there is a gap between list item Ids then will it be able to main that or it will autofill the gap?

Comment: Have you contacted Metalogix support about this? It's difficult for the community to answer a question about third party tools.